# Batch script to move multiple PDF files based on first word to folders that also have the same first word all in the same directory

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a ton of files stored in a single directory which I wish to sort into subfolders based on the first world in their files names.

So, I have thousands of files that are .pdf files that all have different first words (7 numeric characters).

I also have thousands of folders that have different first words 7 numeric characters in the same directory.

I am trying to move all the .pdfs into folders that have the same first word (7 characters).

So I need a batch file that essentially checks a pdf file and checks in the same directory to see if a folder already exists with the same first 7 numeric characters and if it does moves the .pdf into that folder.

If a folder does not exist for the .pdf, it creates a folder based on the .pdf file's first seven characters.

So for example I have a pdf named "1617832_XXXXXXXX_XXX.pdf" and a folder named "1617832_XXXXXXXX" in the same directory, I want the "1617832_XXXXXXXX_***.pdf" to be moved into the existing folder "1617832_XXXXXXXX". However, if folder ""1617832_XXXXXXXX" does not exist, I want a folder created that is titled "1617832" (the first seven characters of file).

Afterwards doing that, it would move on to the next .pdf "4530834__XXXXXXXX_XXX.pdf" and checks the folders to see if it has a matching folder that has the same first word(seven characters) and then moves the file into that folder (if it exists otherwise creates a new folder).

The only batch that comes close but takes too long to run and doesn't create folders if they don't exist is this one:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

pushd c:\folders\

for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /a-d /b *') do (
set filename=%%1&set dirname=!filename:~0,7!

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /ad /b') do (
    set dirid=%%A&set dirid=!dirid:~0,7!

if "!dirid!" equ "!dirname!" move %%1 %%A
  )        
)
```

Any way to do this more efficiently and effectively?

Comment: `if not exist %%A (md %%A)` should create the directories for you ...

Comment: Thank you for reply, i tested that but it did not work. Nothing happened. I want the batch to create the folders based on the first word if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: What should happen if there are 2 folders that match the first 7 characters of the PDF. Ex:
PDF: 1234567MyPDF.PDF
Folder01: 1234567Folder01
Folder02: 1234567Folder02

Comment: Actually I already did such a batch file but it wasn't PDF to copy but JPG images, an in that case the if a more than a folder mached part of the name the JPG was copied to both folders.

Comment: Yes, if two folders that match the first 7 characters I would want the file to be moved to both folders that have the same first 7 characters.

Comment: I've forgotten to change .xml to .pdf in one point at the loop. I've test in my .xml files...

Answer (score 0):

- **Updated** considering this comment: ***Yes, if two folders that match the first 7 characters I would want the file to be moved to both folders that have the same first 7 characters***

You cannot use the move command because moving will make it impossible to make another copy of it (moved file) to another folder where the first 7 characters match, after being moved ...
The command would have to make copies, not move files ...

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

cd /d "O:\Path\Operations\Blank\Blanky\Blank Blank" && cls 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /a:d .\* /b ')do set "_folder=%%~ni" && if exist ".\%%~ni*.pdf" (
for /f tokens^=* %%F in ('dir /a:d /b ".\!_folder:~0,7!*"')do copy ".\%%~ni*.pdf" "%%~dpnF\." )

for %%F in (*.pdf)do set "_file=%%~nF" && call set "_file=!_file:~0,7!" && (
if not exist .\!_file!\. md .\!_file!\ && copy /y "%%~dpnxF" ".\!_file!\." )

:: Deleting these files was copied to multiple folders instead of being moved to folder...
(echo/ if exist .\*.pdf del .\*.pdf /q /f ) & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

First treat the folder and see if any files match; after that, check the remaining files in the folder and without destination

---

If all files have been copied to the respective folder, you need to delete this:
Just remove the **`echo /`** command:

---

```
(echo/ if exist .\*.pdf del .\*.pdf /q /f ) &  %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal && goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Put here the path where the PDFs are:
set "Source=%userprofile%\Desktop\test"

for %%a in ("%Source%\*.PDF") do (
set "File=%%~na"
for /d %%b in ("%Source%\*") do (
set "Folder=%%~nb"
If "!File:~0,7!"=="!Folder:~0,7!" Move "%%a" "%%b"
)
if Exist "%%a" md "!Source!\!File:~0,7!"& move /y "%%a" "!Source!\!File:~0,7!"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This works beautifully! However, the only issue I am having now is regarding path "Source=%userprofile%\Desktop\test". When I test with a path on my desktop it works wonderfully, however when I test with the following path which is on a different drive such as "O:\Path\Operations\Blank\Blanky\Blank Blank" it does not work. I am a noob, what can be used to replace "%userprofile%" so it can be used for other drives and not just the C:\ drive?

Comment: set "Source=O:\Path\Operations\Blank\Blanky\Blank Blank"

Comment: Maybe you put something like:
set "Source="O:\Path\Operations\Blank\Blanky\Blank Blank" (1 quote too much)

Comment: I created this exact same path as you except that I used my pendrive which is w: not o: and It worked:
set "Source=W:\Path\Operations\Blank\Blanky\Blank Blank"
The quotes goes before the variable name (Source) to prevent erros in case the path has special characters...

Comment: Perfect, it works!!! Thank you so much!